# iOS: UIPrintInteractionController How to change the chrome color?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, airprint, uiprintinfo

in iOS, How do I change the color of the chrome around the print popup?

(Objective-C or C# as fine)

Here's how I show the printer:

```
     var printInfo = UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;
     printInfo.OutputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General;

     var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;
     printer.PrintInfo = printInfo;
     printer.PrintFormatter = webView.ViewPrintFormatter;
     printer.ShowsPageRange = true;
     printer.PresentFromBarButtonItem(btnShare, true, (handler, completed, err) => {
        if (!completed && err != null)
        {
           UIAlertHelper.ShowAlert(
              "Unable to Print",
              "Sorry, we were not able to access printers from your device.",
              "Ok",
              null
              );  
        }
     }
     );
```

Here's a screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LbV0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the smartest thing to do here is subclass the popup and initialize it with different border colors, similar to how you subclass uialertview.